# Using an external (computer) keyboard as a MIDI controller

Tags: macos, mac, music, midi, logic

Is it possible to remap a USB (computer) keyboard as a MIDI controller?

Something like Logic's musical typing, except one keyboard functions normally and the other only sends MIDI events.

Comment: Karabiner elements can remap per-keyboard, but not to MIDI events. So any program which can map arbitrary keys to MIDI events will solve this, even if it isn't per-keyboard (I can just hijack extra mouse buttons and such.)

Comment: Can you explain your use case and what you're trying to achieve? There are plenty of 'virtual' MIDI keyboard apps which might suffice? Or notation software apps that let you 'type' music with a QWERTY keyboard. There are also *really* cheap MIDI keyboards, like the Akai LPK25.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I had the problem of wanting to try stuff in Native Instruments Komplete Kontrol when I don't have a MIDI keyboard and this app is a tiny on-screen virtual MIDI keyboard that you can play both with the mouse or with your computer keyboard (needs to have the focus though): https://flit.github.io/projects/midikeys/

If you want to customise the key mappings, you can find the source code here: https://github.com/flit/MidiKeys

[image]